# Fit a line pattern on curve with unknown number of points

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I've got a sample curve which ends theoretically with decreasing exponential. The curve end falls into noise. The sample points are given in log scale.
What I want to do, is to find and fit the linear part of the log curve to retrieve the exponential factor. The trick is that I don't know the starting point neither the ending point of the linear part of the log curve.

The strategy I'm using is to fit a line at each point with at least say 20 points and until the end of the curve is reached. Then from all these regressions, I keep the one with the best determination coefficient.

I did several tests and found that the RMS error increases with the number of points systematically as the curve becomes more and more noisy, so the extracted factor is always computed on the minimum number of samples (20 in this example case).

My question is, is there a more efficient method to compute this factor ? Does increasing the minimum number of samples improve the accuracy of the fit ?

Here a sample curve I want to fit

[image: sample curve]

The computed slope regarding the position in the curve

[image: slope]

And the corresponding RMS error

[image]

Comment: Some questions that may help pin down some characteristics of a model, which will hopefully help to identify the straight part: What is the response before you take logs - is it a count, a scaled count, a measured physical quantity that must be at least 0, one that can be exactly 0, or something else? What is the nature of the noise? Why is the initial part of the curve almost flat? Can you explain why the small increase near 7820 before the slow decrease prior to the part you're more interested in? 
Perhaps a GAM-like model - say linear regression splines with a log-link might work.

Comment: Though that would require some additional effort to identify a suitable model (like how many knots and where to place them), perhaps via LASSO or using cross validation, say. What's a typical sample size (number of points) here?

Comment: To answer your questions: we use a log scale because it is a physical measurement of a signal that is attenuated as it propagates so the loss is just a multiplicative factor in log. The noise is an electronic noise mainly. The flat part is not one, it is linearly decreasing, and the small increase is due to a physical event that increase the measured signal (it is the signature of such an event). Basically, after this event there is no more signal and we only measure the response of the electronics which decreases exponentially (or linearly in log).

Comment: The number of points varies and could be as low as 100 points, but a point is the mean of thousands of samples. But the model is simple, it is a line y=ax+b, but the number of points to use and where to fit it is unknown, thats the goal of my question

Comment: The curve and its part of interest is about 100 points, but the minimum number of points to perform a regression could as low as 4-5 points...

Comment: By "what is the nature of the noise" I don't mean "what is it physically" I mean "what are its statistical properties" (which may well follow from those physical characteristics, but which I'm not in a position to conclude on the basis of your statement) -- is the noise additive and constant variance, for example? Is it independent of the signal? When you say a point is the mean of thousands of observations, is it always the same number (or very close to the same number) of observations? The model (linear in the logs) is clearly  *not* suitable except over a part of the range. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... the problem is you *don't* seem to know where the linear part is; that's the part I am trying to sort out a good approach for. Further, the variance isn't constant so taking logs and fitting a line is not necessarily sensible, even if you did know where the linear part was. My discussion of modelling the entire thing was in the hopes that a suitable model would identify the linear part for you.

Comment: Is the central issue only to estimate the slope of that linear part?

Comment: @Glen_b, the noise is a white noise, totally independent of the signal and additive. Another difficulty is that I dont know the whole curve for sure, I only know that the end of it must be kind of decreasing exponential that falls into noise. Before that, it can be almost anything. And yes, each point is always the mean of the same number of observations.